# MongoError: Use of expired sessions is not permitted when passing session options into another function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, transactions

I'm using expressjs, mongodb (mongoose), with sessions, I start a session which I use inside my middleware, but I need to call an external function where I need to use the session, that is where I get this error

```
(node:18396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Use of expired sessions is not permitted
 

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:18396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18396) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my code

```
module.exports.postBuyerOrder = async (req, res, next) => {
  const session = await mongoose.startSession();
  try {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      const errBody = errHandler.handleValidatorErr(
        errors.array(),
        errHandler.errTypes.LOCAL
      );

      return res.status(422).json(errBody);
    }

    session.startTransaction();

    const opts = { session };

    const buyer = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    const { name, phone, otherPhone, address } = buyer;
    const { notes, products } = req.body;
    const populatedProductsArray = await populateProducts(products);

    let productsFieldValue = await setProductsField(
      populatedProductsArray,
      userRoles.BUYER.value
    );

    let totalPayment = setTotalPaymentField(productsFieldValue);

    const outofStockElements = getInsufficientStockProducts(
      populatedProductsArray
    );

    if (outofStockElements.length > 0) {
      return res.status(405).json({
        warningMsg: "Some products are out of stock, please check your cart.",
        data: outofStockElements,
      });
    }

    const netPrice = productsFieldValue.reduce(
      (init, curr) => init + curr.price,
      0
    );

    const shippingGov = await Shipping.findById(address.govId);

    const ordersNum = await Order.find().countDocuments();

    const order = new Order({
      track: ordersNum + 1,
      name: `${name.firstName} ${name.lastName}`,
      phone,
      otherPhone,
      shipping: address,
      netPrice,
      shippingCost: shippingGov.cost,
      totalPrice: netPrice + shippingGov.cost,
      notes,
      products: productsFieldValue,
      totalPayment: {
        system: totalPayment.system,
        sellers: totalPayment.sellers,
      },
      users: {
        buyer: buyer._id,
        sellers: getSellersArray(productsFieldValue),
      },
    });

    await order.save(opts);

    await handleQuantities(order, handleQuantitiesModes.DEC, { opts }); //The part that causes the error when it is commented in

    await session.commitTransaction();

    return;
    return res.status(200).json({ order });
  } catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    next(err);
  } finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
};



const handleQuantities = async (order, mode, configObject = {}) => {
  try {
    const productsArray = configObject.specficProducts
      ? configObject.specficProducts
      : order.products;
    const opts = configObject.opts;

    productsArray.forEach(async (productEl) => {
      const variantId = productEl.product;
      const variant = await ProductVariant.findById(variantId);

      if (mode == handleQuantitiesModes.INC) {
        variant.stock = variant.stock + 1;
      } else if (mode == handleQuantitiesModes.DEC) {
        variant.stock = variant.stock > 0 ? variant.stock - 1 : 0;
      }

      await variant.save(opts);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

How can I fix this ?, I need to use the session opts out pf the middleware but that is where the error originates, by the way I console.log opts in the handleQuantities function and it is printed successfully, what is the problem here?

Comment: Can you please delete those whole creation of session objects as `{session}` or `opts` and just use and pass `session`? Something that I think you are facing is because of unnecessary complexities. Try to make the question a bit more simple. Second, How long this takes to be executed? Have you checked the session timeout?

Comment: if there is another syntax can u please provide a link of docs that mentions it ?
and problem isn't with timeout, I tried the handleQuantities function without using opts and it is working correctly.

Comment: It won't time out, doesn't take much time as the array I loop over won't be more than 4 elements I think..

Comment: I meant to pass `session` instead of creating something like `opts` object. Pass `session` directly: like `.save(session)` or `handleQuantities(  ,  , session)` and prevent any other object creations including `session` inside. Then try to take a log of `session` inside `handleQuantities()` to check if you are pointing the correct object.

Comment: it is working now, what I changed was switching from forEach to a plain for loop + updating each document only once using $inc operator